# sum every 3 values by group

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to sum  3 values within a data frame by group.

For example:

```
Name Data
A     3
A     5
A     9
A     4
A     3
A     5
A     9
A     4
A     3
A     5
A     9
A     4
B     1
B     5
B     1
B     9
```

Here is what I want:

```
Name Data
A     17
A     18
A     16
A     12
A     17
A     18
A     17
A     12
A     17
A     18
A     N/A
A     N/A
B     7
B     15
B     N/A
B     N/A
```

I am trying to do this iwth dplyr, is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could use `rollsum` (from `zoo`) after grouping by 'Name'

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)
df1 %>% 
    group_by(Name) %>%
    mutate(new = rollsum(Data, 3, fill = NA, align = 'left')) %>%
    ungroup
```

-ouput

```
# A tibble: 16 x 3
   Name   Data   new
   <chr> <int> <int>
 1 A         3    17
 2 A         5    18
 3 A         9    16
 4 A         4    12
 5 A         3    17
 6 A         5    18
 7 A         9    16
 8 A         4    12
 9 A         3    17
10 A         5    18
11 A         9    NA
12 A         4    NA
13 B         1     7
14 B         5    15
15 B         1    NA
16 B         9    NA
```

---

Or using `frollsum` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, new := frollsum(Data, 3, align = 'left'), by = Name]
df1
    Name Data new
 1:    A    3  17
 2:    A    5  18
 3:    A    9  16
 4:    A    4  12
 5:    A    3  17
 6:    A    5  18
 7:    A    9  16
 8:    A    4  12
 9:    A    3  17
10:    A    5  18
11:    A    9  NA
12:    A    4  NA
13:    B    1   7
14:    B    5  15
15:    B    1  NA
16:    B    9  NA
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Name = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B"), Data = c(3L, 5L, 9L, 
4L, 3L, 5L, 9L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 9L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 9L)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-16L))
```

Comment: @AJJebelli i didn't get your comment. Can you show `packageVersion('zoo')`

Comment: my version of zoo is 1.8.9, im not getting NA's for the last rows of the group that should be getting NA's (i.e the last ones)

Comment: @AJJebelli I also have the same version though `packageVersion('zoo')#
[1] ‘1.8.9’`

Comment: when i run your code i get: 
   Name   Data   new
   <chr> <int> <int>
 1 A         3    17
 2 A         5    18
 3 A         9    16
 4 A         4    12
 5 A         3    17
 6 A         5    18
 7 A         9    16
 8 A         4    12
 9 A         3    17
10 A         5    18
11 A         9    14
12 A         4    10
13 B         1     7
14 B         5    15
15 B         1    NA
16 B         9    NA

Comment: @AJJebelli Are you using the same data in my post i.e. the dput data or different one.  Just in case it is a difference in type

Comment: @AJJebelli I tried this again, but still give the same output.  DO you have any other packages loaded having `rollsum` as function name

Comment: @AJJebelli can you try the `frollsum` from `data.table` i.e. `df1 %>% group_by(Name) %>% mutate(new = frollsum(Data, 3,  align = 'left'))`

Comment: @AJJebelli I would suggest to try on a fresh `R` session with only `dplyr` and `zoo` loaded in case of any conflicts with packages

Comment: yeah worked when i reopend R , thanks! as usual